# PhoneGap and Google Maps API V3 "Disabled?"

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3, unauthorized

So, I am building a simple PhoneGap application that loads a Google Maps API V3 view. I have searched far and wide for an answer, but I have not found a thing. I get the following error when trying to load the API:
"Google has disabled the use of Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API V3 on this site."

I have tried everything. In Cordova, I have all domains whitelisted ("*"), and the same in the Google Play Developer Console ("*"). I have even tried whitelisting "file://", but no such luck.

What drives me nuts is, when I use my code outside of the scope of PhoneGap, it works fine. Can anybody shed some light? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue.
I changed the Google developers console Api key referrers from '*' to '' and then solved my problem.

**Just leave the referrers field it blank.**

I hope it help. I spent about 4 hours to solve it :@